# How to access files Cross-Project in php?

Tags: php

I have projectA which has a.php and I have projectB which has b.php
How do i access a.php from b.php.All this projects lie in the same root as HOME
Please help

<?php
    class B {
        function getB() {
            return "B";
        }
    }   
<?php
    include '/projectB/B.php';
     class AA {
        function getA() {
            $objB=new B();
            echo $objB->getB();
        }
    }

    $obj=new AA();
    $obj->getA();
    ?>

Error thrown is 
Class 'B' not found in C:\wamp\www\projectA\AA.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If file a.php is in another directory, the path can be either relative (to your current file a.php directory) or absolute (based on your servers absolute file path).

Example of relative:

```
<?php 
     include('../a.php'); // one directory back, as the file path is always relative to the file in which include (or require or any of the others) is being called.
?>
```

Example of absolute:

```
<?php
     include('/path/to/server/root/some/folder/a.php'); // absolute path 
?>
```

Hope this helps.

---

### UPDATE

You keep saying "it's wrong" or "it doesn't work" but you really have not explained your file structure very well. So I am going to ASSUME that your folder structure looks like this, for examples sake:

- WEB ROOT

  - ProjectA

    - a.php
  - ProjectB

    - b.php

Now, if you were inside of a.php, you could require b.php as follows:

`require_once('../ProjectB/b.php');`

If you were inside of b.php and wanted to include a.php, it could be as follows:

`include_once('../ProjectA/a.php');`

Note, I have used include AND require, it's up to you to research which to use.

Comment: It should also be said that there are other methods, such as require, require_once, include and include_once. To get a good idea of the differences, read this post on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418473/when-should-i-use-require-once-vs-include

Comment: It is throwing an error saying Warning: include(): Failed opening '/projectB/B.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\projectA\AA.php on line 2

Comment: You are using an absolute path in your comment. / means that you are starting FROM the system root, eg "C:" on windows or "/" on linux / unix. Try either "projectB/B.php" or "./projectB/B.php"

Comment: Thanks it works when i give the full path include 'C:\wamp\www\projectB\B.php';
Is there any better ways i can handle this?I mean if i deploy the code tomorrow in another system,the path changes

Comment: Yes, using `__DIR__` will result in the full absolute path to the directory that your file is currently in. I don't understand why you want to use absolute paths when relative paths are hassle free and won't break. Also, bear in mind that directory separators on windows ("\") are different to Linux, Unix & OSX which all use "/". You can replace your slashes with the PHP constant "DS"

Comment: Thanks,I would go with relative paths,as they are hassle free.Can i also address my problem using namespaces?What are my options if i donot want to write includes in my files?

Comment: You have no choice but to include or require the file if they are separate files. Even if you name spaced, you'd still need a reference to class A (or B) from the other file. If I were you, I would ignore name spacing for now. When you have a better understanding of OOP, take a look then.

Answer (score 0):

if a.php and b.php is in the same folder:

in b.php:

```
<?php
  include_once(__DIR__ . '../projectA/A.php');
?>
```

`__DIR__` is the dynamic path of folder from b.php.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

if it is very important that a is include in b.php use require:

```
<?php
  require_once(__DIR__ . '../projectA/a.php');
?>
```

Comment: And provide the complete path if it is in another directory

Comment: There is absolutely no need for `__DIR__` as include is always relative to the directory of the file in which it is being called from.

Comment: It is wrong to say that it is important that the OP use 'require' or 'require_once', it all depends on his scenario.

Comment: in some cases it is better to use __DIR__ with an include. It does not hurt to write these few letters. and as I said, IF it is important that one file include to another he has to use require, in some other cases it is enough to use include.

Comment: The two files are not in the same folder,they are in different projects.However the two projects are in the same folder.And the ans is not working.

Answer (score 0):

just requre a.php from b.php
here is the code:

require_once('a.php');

Answer (score 0):

Classes are confined to the 'space' in which they are created. You can not, in theory, cross pollinate classes.

You have two options:

**1) Create a Singleton class** (see [Global PHP class in functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247354/global-php-class-in-functions))

**2) Extend class AA from class BB, example:**

```
Class AA extends class B{
   // Yada yada yada
}
```

It's worth reading the following two resource:

http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php